# Difculdade para entender como funcionam os eventlisteners em Java?

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

**Saudações caros colegas programadores**

Vocês estão bem? Espero que sim

Estou fazendo essa publicação pois estou com muita dificuldade pra entender um parâmetro específico dos listeners do Android Studio, em especifico do OnClick, e como eu percebi que muitas funções do ambiente de desenvolvimento carregam essa mesma estrutura, decidi fazer esse tópico

O código em questão proposto pelo exercicio é o seguinte.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText precoGasolina;
private EditText precoEtanol;
private Button botaoVerificar;
private TextView textoResultado;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    precoGasolina =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_gasolina);
    precoEtanol = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_etanol);
    textoResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_resultado);
    botaoVerificar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_calcular);

    botaoVerificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Recupera valores digitados
            String textoPrecoAlcool = precoEtanol.getText().toString();
            String textoPrecoGasolina = precoGasolina.getText().toString();
            //Conveterter valores strings para numeros;
            Double valorEtanol = Double.parseDouble(textoPrecoAlcool);
            Double valorGasolina = Double.parseDouble(textoPrecoGasolina);

            double resultado = valorEtanol/valorGasolina;

            if (resultado >= 0.7){
                textoResultado.setText(resultado + "É melhor utilizar gasolina");
            }else{
                textoResultado.setText(resultado + "É melhor utilizar Etanol");
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

A minha grande duvida fica dentro do

`onClick(View v){`

Eu sei para que o argumento View v funciona, ele serve para acessar atributos do botão, mas a minha duvida é como eu posso passar um argumento sem fazer referência ao botão e ele conseguir interpretar que eu estou tratando o objeto botão?